# JMESPath - Ansible-AWX - JSON

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath, ansible-awx

I have the following json where i wish to extract the name based on externalId (2720135)

```
 {  
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "f15073f7-c934-479f-bed9-07b6c3402b60",
      "name": "360 Index",
      "description": "360 Index",
      "displayName": "360 Index",
      "fullName": "360 Index",
      "type": "Application",
      "tags": [],
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "externalId",
          "data": {
            "type": "ExternalId",
            "externalId": "2720135",
            "comment": null,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "externalUrl": null
          },
          "dataType": null
        }
      ],
      "relations": [],
      "milestones": [],
      "createdAt": "2022-07-06T19:00:20.202009Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-09-21T11:51:45.887413Z",
      "documents": [],
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "lxState": "BROKEN_QUALITY_SEAL",
      "level": 1,
      "qualitySealStatus": "BROKEN",
      "score": "NaN",
      "rev": 51,
      "lxExcludeFromQuota": false,
      "naFields": [],
      "subscriptions": [],
      "permittedReadACL": [],
      "permittedWriteACL": []
    }
  ],
  "cursor": "bWl4OjAjRFhGMVpYSjVRVzVrUm1WMFkyZ0JBQUFBQUFCWkN6b1dlamhIYzBSd1pVeFVSUzFCTVdwT2NFZHpTMW95UVE9PSUxNjY0MzYzMTQ5NDM1"
}
```

What i have tried to only select the keys "name" and "fields"

```
   data[].{name:name,fields:fields}
```

Question: How can i filter to only get the name based on "externalId": "2720135"

Result should be: "360 Index"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the data for testing

```yaml
shell> cat data5.yml
data:
  - createdAt: '2022-07-06T19:00:20.202009Z'
    fields:
    - data:
        externalId: '2720135'
        status: ACTIVE
      name: externalId
    level: 1
    name: 360 Index
  - createdAt: '2022-07-06T19:00:20.202009Z'
    fields:
    - data:
        externalId: '2720136'
        status: ACTIVE
      name: externalId
    level: 1
    name: 336 Index
  - createdAt: '2022-07-06T19:00:20.202009Z'
    fields:
    - data:
        externalId: '2720137'
        status: ACTIVE
      name: externalId
    level: 1
    name: 337 Index
```

---

For example, the declarations below

```yaml
result: "{{ data|json_query(_query) }}"
_query: '[?fields[?data.externalId == to_string(`2720135`)]].name'
```

give

```yaml
  result:
  - 360 Index
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    - data5.yml

  vars:

    result: "{{ data|json_query(_query) }}"
    _query: '[?fields[?data.externalId == to_string(`2720135`)]].name'

    resul2: "{{ data|json_query('[].{name: name,
                                     fields: fields[].data.externalId|[0] }') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result
    - debug:
        var: resul2|to_yaml
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  result:
    - 360 Index

  resul2|to_yaml: |-
    - {fields: '2720135', name: 360 Index}
    - {fields: '2720136', name: 336 Index}
    - {fields: '2720137', name: 337 Index}
```

---

You can create a dictionary that would make the searching trivial, e.g.

```yaml
id_name: "{{ resul2|items2dict(key_name='fields', value_name='name') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  id_name:
    '2720135': 360 Index
    '2720136': 336 Index
    '2720137': 337 Index
```